# Why does sIFR chop off letters?

Tags: css, html, sifr

What would cause the bottom of characters like p, f, y to be invisible when using [sIFR](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/)?

Comment: I sort of got around this by adding some bottom padding to the .sIFR-alternate class style.  But I'll be curious to see if there's a better solution.  For what it's worth, this only seems to happen to me in FireFox.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks. It's a consolation to know I'm not the only one at least.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`line-height` is too small? There's some coverage about using `line-height` correctly with sIFR [here](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3/font-sizing).

Answer (score 0):

It's a Flash issue. You can help Flash render things correctly through the `tuneHeight`/`tuneWidth` and `offsetTop`/`offsetLeft` arguments (sIFR 3).